# MongoParseError: Invalid connection string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, connection, database-connectivity

I am trying to connect MongoDB database with this code but when running it I get the error (see the error below after the code). The initial error was in the line where it was resolved by adding `useNewUrlParser: true` but even after this I still get more errors. I am using MongoDB version 4.0.1. Does anybody know how to resolve this error?

```
mongoose.connect('User://localhost:27017/User',{ useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Error while running this code:

> (node:11068) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
>       (node:11068) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 16):

Instead of `User://localhost`, use `mongodb://localhost/`
I had the same problem.

Comment: For me `mongodb://mongo/` worked. where `mongo` is the docker service name.

Answer (score 8):

I was receiving the same error, then I used:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/[yourDbName]", {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
```

Substitute `[yourDbName]` for your MongoDB database's name:

Answer (score 4):

The host you have written is not correct, and it should be

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/User',{ useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this and it should work,

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mycargarage', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  In my case, the issue was caused by my password.  Apparently, if there are special characters in the password, you need to use the HEX value.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the // after the dots to indicate the localhosts, it is for mongodb 5

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const MONGODB_HOST = 'mongodb://localhost/'
const MONGODB_DB = 'usuarios'

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_HOST,{
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true

})

    .then(db => console.log('Db connection established'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**   *mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);*

db.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose =require('mongoose')
const app = express();

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database_name', {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
.catch((err) => console.log(err))

app.listen(3000,()=>{ console.log("Running on port 3000") })
```

```
npm i express mongoose
```

```
node db.js
```