# 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: Invalid connection string' problem is going on i didn't know what is problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

homePage.create is not working. i think my problem is here
`"mongoose.connect('mongo://localhost:27017/Socialuser', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });"`

### App.js file

```
          const express = require('express');
            const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
            const mongoose = require('mongoose');
            let homePage = require('./models/home');
            
            mongoose.connect('mongo://localhost:27017/Socialuser', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
            
            const app = express();
            
            app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
            
            app.get('/', (req, res) => {
                res.render('landing.ejs');
            });
            
            app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
                res.render('loginSignUp.ejs');
            });
            
            app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
            
            
            
                console.log(homePage);
                homePage.create({ name: 'wasim', image: 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg' }, (err, home) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('saved');
                    }
                });
            });
            
            app.listen(3000, () => {
                console.log('server started at port 3000');
            });
```

here is my home.js file.it's the home schema file

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
    let homePageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        image: String
        // comments: [ String ]
    });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Home', homePageSchema);
```

what is the actual problem i didn't getting what is going on. 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: Invalid connection string' .....this problem is going

```
    (node:22464) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
        at parseConnectionString (C:\Users\wasim\Desktop\social\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\uri_parser.js:547:21)
        at connect (C:\Users\wasim\Desktop\social\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:277:3)
        at C:\Users\wasim\Desktop\social\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:222:5
        at maybePromise (C:\Users\wasim\Desktop\social\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:662:3)
        at MongoClient.connect (C:\Users\wasim\Desktop\social\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:218:10)
        at C:\Users\wasim\Desktop\social\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:713:12
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\wasim\Desktop\social\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:710:19)
        at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\wasim\Desktop\social\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:335:15)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wasim\Desktop\social\app.js:6:10)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
        at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
    (node:22464) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
```

This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:22464) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoParseError: Invalid connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721216/mongoparseerror-invalid-connection-string)

Comment: The formatting of this question is the worst I've seen in a while. Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: `mongodb://localhost:27017/Socialuser` try this

Answer (score 1):

```
    1) Please use this 
    
    mongodb://localhost:27017/Socialuser
    
    Instead of -
    
    mongo://localhost:27017/Socialuser
    
    2) mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/[yourDbName]", {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true
    });
    
    In your case yourDbName = Socialuser

Hope this will solve your problem!
```